# Symfony2: No route found for "GET /sitemap.xml"

Tags: php, symfony, sitemap, fosrestbundle

When I request `sitemap.xml`, I'm getting `No route found for "GET /sitemap.xml"`. I need to serve `sitemap.xml` from the `/web` folder. So some reason Symfony starts to look for a route. I think `config.yml` is messed up. I'm using FOSRestBundle which works fine but might interfere with routing.

Relevant parts from the `config.yml`:

```
framework:
    translator: { fallback: en }
    secret:          %secret%
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection:
        enabled:        false
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        save_path: %kernel.root_dir%/var/sessions
    fragments:       ~
fos_rest:
    cache_dir:      %kernel.cache_dir%/fos_rest
    routing_loader:
        default_format: json
    service:
        templating: templating
        serializer: jms_serializer.serializer
    serializer:
        serialize_null: false
    param_fetcher_listener: force
    body_listener: true
    body_converter:
        enabled: true
    format_listener:
        rules:
            - { path: '^/api', fallback_format: json } 
            - { path: '^/', priorities: [ 'html', '*/*'], fallback_format: html, prefer_extension: true }
    view:
        default_engine: twig
        formats:
            json: true
        view_response_listener: forcebundle
    unauthorized_challenge: "" 
    access_denied_listener:
        json: true    
    exception:
        codes:
            'Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException': 404
        messages:
            'Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException': true
            'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException': true
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you think FOSRestBundle can be the problem? Isn't it normal that every url call pass trough the router? Or you handle your sitemap by creating a route [link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cmf/bundles/seo/sitemap.html) or you made a special acces in your nginx/apache configuration to serve this url.

Comment: As others mentioned, there is nothing related to Symfony, your webserver config have to contain rule like: if file exist > return file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope. The issue here is in your `.htaccess` or similar rewrite mechanism.

The default `.htaccess` that ships with Symfony inncludes these rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .? - [L]
```

which means, "if a an actual file exists, just serve it". In your case this rule is not applied for some reasons, so everything is passed on to `app.php` and Symfony routing, but Symfony has no `/sitemap.xml` route, thus the 404 error.

Comment: Indeed, it was an issue with `.htaccess`. In my case, Symfony app in being served from `/api` subfolder , and the RewriteRule for sitemaps in the root `.htaccess` was not correct. The correct one is: `RewriteRule ^sitemap(.*).xml$ api/web/sitemap$1.xml [L]`